# Which verse/scripture is this shloka from? (na karoti svayaṁ kiṅchit sṛṣṭiādika mahān)

Tags: scripture, puranas, bhagavata-purana, reference-request, shloka

I am trying to identify the source of the sloka. I came across this sloka while listening to a lecture, It sounds mostly like from **Bhagwata Mahapurana** but somehow I am not able to find it researching online

> na karoti svayaṁ kiṅchit sṛṣṭiādika mahān

न करोति स्वयं किंचित सृष्टिआदिक महान

It roughly translates to:
`Sri Krishna does not by himself does the task of creating material world but rather delegate it to other`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one also has a slighty different version occuring in the [Padma Purana Verse 5.82.71](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%AB_(%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83)/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A6%E0%A5%AE%E0%A5%A8):

> मायागुणैर्यतोमेंऽशा कुर्वंति सर्जनादिकम् ।
> न करोमि स्वयं किंचित्सृष्ट्यादिकमहं शिव ॥ ७१ ॥
>
> māyāguṇairyatomeṃ'śā kurvaṃti sarjanādikam |
> na karomi svayaṃ kiṃcitsṛṣṭyādikamahaṃ śiva || 71 ||

[English translation of the chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365394.html). The context is a boon received by Śiva who wished to see the form of Nārāyaṇa. This results in a meet and conversation with Kṛṣṇa.

> 65-73a. Then, having laughed, Kṛṣṇa, speaking (sweetly) like nectar, said to me: “O Rudra, having known your desire, I have appeared before you, since you have today seen this uncommon form of mine, which is the embodiment of spotless love that is solidified and of goodness, intelligence and joy (i.e. Brahman), which is (at the same time) formless, qualityless, (all-)pervading, actionless, and higher than the highest. The groups of the Upaniṣads describe this faultless form of mine only. Because my qualities have not sprung from the constituents of Prakṛti, and because of their being endless, and because of their not being effected, they call me the qualityless lord. O Maheśvara (i.e. Śiva), because this form of mine is not visible to the physical eyes, all the Vedas describe me to be formless. The wise ones also know me to be Brahman, as a part of the supreme spirit, because of my (all-)prevading nature. As I am not the agent of the visible world, they (also) call me actionless; since my portions through power of Māyā perform creation etc., **I do not myself perform creation etc., O Śiva.** O Mahādeva, I am overcome with the love of these cowherdesses. I do not know any other act, even myself, O Nārada(?). Being influenced by her love, I always sport with her.